# What does "contact" mean in relation to the Barrier power "Damage" modifier?

Tags: savage-worlds, savage-worlds-adventure-edition

What does "contact" mean in relation to the Barrier power's Damage modifier (see p.155 of the Savage Worlds Adventure Edition v4.1 PDF).

Does someone have to actually touch the Barrier? Or does hitting the Barrier with, for example, a sword, also count as "contact"?

Comment: I edited the attribution slightly to include the game version (Adventure Edition) included in your tag to make it a bit more obvious. If you dislike this change, please roll it back.

Answer (score 2):

### Touching

*Savage Worlds* is pretty good about making game terms stand out with various font alterations. Contact has no such alteration, and isn't defined anywhere else in the rules, therefore it is using the common English definitions.

> **Contact** *noun* - the state or condition of physical touching.

Poking it with a stick, even a sharp metal stick like a sword, isn't contact. Poking it with your finger, nose, foot, or other body part would be contact.

Using someone else's body part, severed or not, would be contact for that body part but probably not for you.

Obviously, the GM has final say on what is or isn't "contact" for a damaging *barrier*.

Comment: Good point. So I can chop my way through the Barrier without worrying about Damage, but if I wanted to climb over it, I'd be contacting it, and would take Damage